# how to drag and drop and resize a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all i am trying to drag drop and resize a dynamically created table , table is created in JS ,

```
function addRow() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type ="text" id="txtfirstname_' + count + '"></input>';
    row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">' + '<input type="button" id="edit_' + count + '" value = "Edit" onClick="Javacsript:editRow(this)">';
    $('#txtfirstname_' + count).val(firstname.value);
    $('#txtfirstname_' + count).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    count++;
    document.getElementById("firstname").value = "";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ytrgvan/

Here i am trying to create a table with the above some details given by user in the same page , i want my table to be draggable and droppable to any place and also want to resize my table , all the values in table are in textbox and has couple of dynamically created buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you use the AJAX Control toolkit, you could put a panel around the table and add the DragPanel and ResizableControl extenders to the panel.